# Does json support arabic characters?

Tags: php, ajax, json

i want to ask quick question, is json support arabic characters i mean when i search for something like following

```
$values = $database->get_by_name('معاً'); 
echo json_encode(array('returnedFromValue' => $value."<br/>"));
```

also I'm looking for arabic result from the database, the returned values will be like this

```
{"returnedFromValue":"\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0649<br\/>"}{"returnedFromValue":"\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0649<br\/>"}
```

what I'm missing here ? is it better to use XML in term of supporting the arabic characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is, just like XML, some kind of data-interchange-format. it's not addicted to a special charset, so arabic characters should be fine if u use a charset that supports these characters ([UFT-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) for example).

Comment: The JSON specification states that "JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8.", so it is "addicted" to a very small number of character sets.

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.4.0 will support a special option for `json_encode()` called `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. This stops the default behaviour of converting characters to their `\uXXXX` form.

```
$value = 'معاً';
echo json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// Outputs: "معاً"
```

Answer (score 0):

These `\u0627`-numbers are the Unicode-codepoints for your arabic letters. PHP uses them rather than the raw UTF-8 serialization, but they are there. So yes, JSON does support it. If the result string was printed out client-side (using Javascript) you would see the letters again.