# How can I get data from MySql using PHP in my Xcode app?

Tags: php, json, xcode

I am using the code below to retrieve data from MySql using PHP file depending on the user input, every thing is good when the input in English, but when the input is in **Arabic** the Xcode shows error and terminate the app:

Xcode:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; //create instance of NSUSerDefaults
NSString *qasidaName = [defaults objectForKey:@"qasidaName"];
self.lbOne.text = qasidaName;


NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"mytitle=%@",[self.lbOne text]];
NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/MyDomain.com/checkphp.php"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);



if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300){
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/MyDomain.com/checkphp.php?title=%@",[self.lbOne text]];
NSURL *jsonUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];
jasonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < jasonArray.count; i++) {
NSString *cUserName = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"userName"];
NSString *cTitle = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"title"];
NSString *cComments = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"comments"];
NSString *cTimeC = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"commentsTime"];
NSString *cDateC = [[jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"commentsDate"];

[listArray addObject:[[ListOfObjects alloc]initWithUserName:cUserName andTitle:cTitle andComments:cComments andtimeC:cTimeC andDateC:cDateC]];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Can any one tell me what do i need to change in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the arabic case you can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` for default behaviour like

```
echo json_encode($yourdata, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Also use `charset=utf-8` also Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513235/does-json-support-arabic-characters)

Try to get response in NSArray then convert it in JSON or see the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJZcD3hfs3k) which may helps you.

Comment: The PHP file has no problem, it is reading the Arabic, but my problem with Xcode, it shows error as soon as my input in Arabic and terminate the app.         return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));